# Is it possible to build an Android SDK and iOS SDK using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, sdk

In my company we are building Android SDKs and iOS SDKs. The reason why we are building SDKs is because we don't want to give away our code and methods to ours customers, we just want to hide how we connect to some services.

So i would like to know if is it possible to build an Android SDK and iOS SDK using React Native?, in the end you have to compile the code in order to create Android and iOS versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Actually, RN is not a good idea for your question C/C++ does.**

About ReactNative:

*RN using js to build an App on Android/iOS Platform which using JavaScriptCore to call native code.*

About C/C++:

*C/C++ is truly cross-platform you can build a static library for your customers to use Also you can build SO(android)/framework(iOS) library for then.*

Comment: Thanks for your response, up to now we have a Android developer and a iOS developer, so we can continue working in that way.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with the above answers. Using RN's Native Bridge's you can definitely create a RN based micro front-end; essentially an app within an app.

RN can compile down to a native project, and you can invoke a RN developed application from a native project by exposing APIs from the compiled version of your RN SDK.

Plaid's RN PlaidLink SDK is a good example of this.

This is my current project. If other developers are interested, comment on this answer and I'll be happy to update the thread once I'm done.

**Update 1/14/2021
Looks like the RN organization added stepsf
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios

Cheers

Comment: I would like to see your project. It would help me a lot.

Comment: @alimcharaniya Anything new? it sounds very interesting (probably for many)

Comment: Can you please share Steps to create RN SDK and use in Native project from Start to End

Comment: React Native added an article for achieving this. https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios

Answer (score 3):

Only if your customer is also going to be using React Native.  Its extremely painful to call react native code from native, and if you aren't using RN you'd have a significant cost in RAM and time to start it up.  If you're writing an SDK I would not recommend it, as RN is used in a tiny fraction of the number of apps published.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i was reading on internet similar questions and I'm agree with you, we will continue with Android and iOS SDKs. Thanks!

Comment: @gabe-sechan, Is that still the case today? I have a View with RN, I intend to wrap it as SDK for integrating into different apps. Do you think I should avoid it?

Comment: If you're integrating it into other RN apps, that's fine.  If you want to integrate it into a native app, its probably a really bad idea for that app. @IlanLevy